# SSH server last login message implementation

Tags: go, ssh, server

I implemented a SSH server daemon in Go using the `crypto/ssh` library and I would like to implement the "last login message" functionnality that is present in OpenSSH: when a user connect to the server, he receive a message indicating the IP/Time of its last connection.

To authenticate users, the SSH server uses the PublicKeyCallback like this.

```
&ssh.ServerConfig{
        NoClientAuth: false,
        PublicKeyCallback: func(c ssh.ConnMetadata, pk ssh.PublicKey) (*ssh.Permissions, error) {
            pkstr := string(pk.Marshal())

            akmu.Lock()
            defer akmu.Unlock()
            if _, ok := authorizedKeys[pkstr]; ok {
                authorizedKeys[pkstr].last = time.Now()
                return nil, nil
            }
            return nil, errors.New("unauthorized public key")
        },
    }
```

The `authorizedKeys` variable maps a marshaled publick key to a type that should store the Origin ip address and time of the last connection of a public key.

```
var authorizedKeys map[string]*keyHistory

type keyHistory struct {
    Origin   net.Addr
    Time     time.Time
}
```

The problem is that the only place where the public key that is used to autenticate a user is available is during the `PublicKeyCallback` execution, but registering the connection event here won't guarante that the connection process won't fail later on.

What I mean by later on is the differents steps that happen after a public key has been authorized :

- reject all non-session channels
- accept the session channel
- creates a new terminal with the session channel and the conn (using own wrapped implem of `terminal.Terminal`)
- process others requests (`shell`, `pty-req`, `window-change`)
- run a loop to read the inputs of the terminal with `terminal.ReadLine()`

Ideally the connection event ip/time would be recorded just before running the terminal loop to ensure that it correspond to a successfull login. Unfortunately, at this point, only the underlying `ssh.ServerConn` of the terminal is available and it isn't possible to link it back to a public key.

Any leads to implement a similar functionnality ? Any example or link to a project that would have achieved the same thing would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just cache the value during `PublicKeyCallback`, and then move it `authorizedKeys` if the login was successful? You also have a data race around `authorizedKeys`, and need some sort of synchronization around the map.

Comment: @JimB How would you cache it and link a successfull connection to a private key since multiples connections could be run concurently ? (temp cache by publick-key/`net.Addr` pair. could work since host:port of origin should be unique)
The `authorizedKeys` map is backed by a `sync.Mutex` of course.

Comment: @JimB Okay so your idea was the good one. I cache the connection attampt details mapped to a publick key, and where I assume the connection is a success I update the last successfull attempt details with the data found in cache (matching is done with the `net.Addr` which should be unique since it has the form host:port) and write the last connection details (if any) to the client. Dunno why I have not thought about this earlier.